# Angular npm dependency - could not resolve - capacitor

Tags: node.js, angular, capacitor

If I execute the command:

> npm install @capacitor/push-notifications

I get the following stacktrace:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @capacitor/core@4.8.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@capacitor/core
npm ERR!   @capacitor/core@"^4.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @capacitor/core@"^5.0.0" from @capacitor/push-notifications@5.0.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@capacitor/push-notifications
npm ERR!   @capacitor/push-notifications@"^5.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

My question now would be how to solve this?

[EDIT]
My package.json looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
"@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
"@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
"@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
"@capacitor/android": "4.6.1",
"@capacitor/app": "1.0.6",
"@capacitor/core": "^4.5.0",
"@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.3",
"@capacitor/keyboard": "1.1.3",
"@capacitor/push-notifications": "^5.0.6",
"@capacitor/splash-screen": "^4.1.4",
"@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.6",
"@capgo/capacitor-updater": "^4.17.46",
```

Comment: It works as expected in nodejs 16 - ubuntu. I tried now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhrUR.png  Try in another machine or with docker to validate if it is something in your machine and nothing is wrong with the library

Comment: No, for me it does not work, I work with a Win10 machine

Comment: And your os details are? If it works in all the machines except in yours, the problem is not with the library.